# What would be the English for 公示？

Tags: meaning

I have this definition for 公示：指政府机关或团体下达的指示、通告等。

and this sentence: 卡拉OK版权费征收标准的公示一出，老板和消费者对此都有不同的反应。

After the copyright-fee levy standard for Karaoke (bars) was 公示'published'(??), bosses and customers reacted differently.

Maybe 'enacted'， ‘enforced’??

Comment: How about 'introduced'?

Comment: public announcement?

Answer (score 3):

公：public；示：notify
so, put these characters together, 公示means “to notify the public about some events or public decision” or "something that publicly notifies the population about some events" .

Thus, to your question, 公示 is a noun, "一出"is a verb means "release". And in your case, 公式was translated as "standard" which makes sense, because industry standard made by some public organization can be seen as "something that notify the public about some public decision".

Comment: The translation was mine, not from a book. I was guessing at 公示。Standard would be 标准 I think， there is no 公式  in my text. This 版权费 is required by a 政府机关或团体, left to their own devices, no one would pay! If it is a noun, it could be 'announcement', but that does not fit well, then rather 'announced' or 'notified the public'.

Comment: Would you like to try and translate the whole sentence?

Comment: Once the PSA for Karaoke royalties standards was published, owners and patrons all had different reactions.

Answer (score 0):

- make known to the public
- notify (the public)
- inform (the public)
- proclaim [e.g. a state organ; this doesn't fit your context]
- release (information)
- to display (information)
- or simply: announce [as in the comment above]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you know 告示. I think 公示 is the official version of 告示. So I think 公示 = official bulletin (or something similar).

So the whole sentence should be:
After the official bulletin for copyright-fee levy standard for Karaoke was publicized, bosses and customers reacted differently.